# Angular 2 App with Express server not responding to API calls

Tags: node.js, angular, express, heroku

I have a angular2 app hosted on heroku. The server is a node/express one.

Example: When my app makes an api to posts (appurl.com/posts) it is structured as such: appurl.com/api/posts

- all api calls are made at appurl.com/api/~ whatever
- all data is sent to appurl.com/~ whatever

However on the live version of my application, every call to the api comes up with a 404. This does not happen when I am developing locally, the api works just fine, as well as on a version where the API and App are two seperate projects - this version would be classed as a 'MEAN2' app I guess, where the above problems have occurred...

I always get this 404 error for each api call I try:

```
zone.js:2019 GET https://appurl.com/api/posts/ 404 (Not Found)
```

server.js (express)

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const http = require('http');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const favicon = require('serve-favicon');
const logger = require('morgan');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

let index = require('./server/routes/index');
let posts = require('./server/routes/posts');

let app = express();

const port = process.env.PORT || '3000';

let uriString = process.env.MONGODB_URI || "mongodb://localhost:27017/test-db";
mongoose.connect(uriString, function(err, res) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log('Success connected to: ' + uriString)
    }

});

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/dist'))); //enable for build

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var allowedOrigins = ['https://www.appurl.com', 'https://appurl.herokuapp.com', 'https://appurl.com', 'http://localhost:3000'];
    var origin = req.headers.origin;
    if (allowedOrigins.indexOf(origin) > -1) {
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', origin);
    }
    // res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS', 'PUT');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    return next();
});

app.use('/api/', index);
app.use('/api/posts', posts);


app.get('*', (req, res, next) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'));
});

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`server running on port:${port}`))


module.exports = app;
```

post.js (server/routes/post.js)

```
let express = require('express');
let router = express.Router();
let PostController = require('../controllers/post.js')
let jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
let User = require('../models/user');

// get posts
router.route('/').get(PostController.getAllPosts); // getAllPosts just returns all posts from the DB, this works locally

module.exports = router;
```

post.service.ts

```
    import { Injectable, EventEmitter } from "@angular/core";
    import { Http, Headers, Response } from "@angular/http";
    // observable lib
    import 'rxjs/Rx';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
    import { Observable } from "rxjs";
    import { Post } from "./post.model";
    import { ErrorService } from '../shared/errors/error.service';
    import { NotificationService } from '../shared/notifications/notification.service';
    import { Router } from '@angular/router';

    const api = '/api/posts/';

    @Injectable()
    export class PostService {
        private posts: Post[] = [];
        private post: Post;
        postIsEdit = new EventEmitter<Post>();

        constructor(private http: Http, private _es: ErrorService, private _ns: NotificationService, private _r: Router) {
        }

        getPosts() {
            return this.http.get(api)
                .map((response: Response) => {
                    const posts = response.json().obj;
                    let transformedPosts: Post[] = [];
                    for (let post of posts) {
                        transformedPosts.push(new Post(
                            post.title,
                            post.description,
                            post.location,
                            post.author,
                            post.user,
                            post.date_created,
                            post.timestamp,
                            post.userId,
                            post._id)
                        );
                    }
                    this.posts = transformedPosts;
                    return transformedPosts;
                })
            // .catch((error: Response) => Observable.throw(error.json()));
        }
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "testapp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "heroku-prebuild": "npm install -g http-server",
    "heroku-postbuild": "ng build --prod",
    "start": "http-server dist/",
    "ng": "ng",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/core": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/http": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/router": "^3.3.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.24",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.49.0",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.3.0",
    "body-parser": "~1.15.2",
    "connect-multiparty": "^2.0.0",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.3",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "express": "~4.14.0",
    "express-fileupload": "^0.1.3",
    "express-session": "^1.15.2",
    "hbs": "~4.0.1",
    "imgix-core-js": "^1.0.5",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^5.7.0",
    "mongoose": "^4.4.12",
    "mongoose-unique-validator": "^1.0.2",
    "morgan": "~1.7.0",
    "multer": "^1.3.0",
    "multer-s3": "^2.7.0",
    "nodemailer": "^4.0.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
    "s3fs": "^2.5.0",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "typescript": "~2.0.3",
    "uuid": "^3.0.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "~4.0.13",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "^4.0.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick was in the package.json, changed:

```
"start": "http-server dist/",
```

to

```
"start": "node server.js",
```

I was using a different package.json locally.